# Potentiometer Specs

Tags: potentiometer

I have a schematic for an audio amplifier that states that the volume potentiometer is 20KA. What does 20KA mean in the context of a potentiometer? I don't see anything else that states its total resistance.

[image]

Comment: The use of A/B/C is a ridiculous standard. Seriously wonder who had that idea... it really should have been possible to squeeze `LIN`/`LOG` on the pots and thus preclude the inevitable confusion and conflicting assignments.

Comment: Kiloampere? Wow, that's a great amplifier! I want one, too. Does it go directly on a 230kV power station as well?

Answer (score 23):

The "A" part stands for audio taper.

- "B" would be linear taper and
- "C" is a reverse audio taper: -

[image]

Image from [this website](https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-types/potentiometer-taper/#)

[What taper means in this context](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-are-audio-taper-potentiometers): -

> Audio Taper Potentiometers are log taper potentiometers that are
> specifically designed for use in audio applications.
>
> Audio taper potentiometers are the potentiometers that are used for
> volume control in audio devices. This includes headphones, headsets,
> computer speakers, or any volume-altering devices. The main thing
> differentiating audio taper potentiometers from others is that audio
> taper potentiometers are log tapers. Most potentiometers used are
> linear tapers, meaning any turn in the wiper of the potentiometer
> changes the resistance linearly. Audio Taper Potentiometers are log
> tapers, which are potentiometers that change resistance
> logarithmically as you turn the wiper.
>
> This is crucial for audio applications because logarithmic change in
> resistance, not linear change, is what is desired. Ours ears perceive
> sound in a logarithmic fashion. If you were to use a linear
> potentiometer for volume control, increasing and decreasing sound, the
> volume changes would not turn out right. A linear taper's adjustment
> grows far too rapidly as the pot is turned up from zero. This means
> that the volume levels shoot up too high right when you beginning
> turning it up. Volume control then is very difficult. For linear
> tapers, the volume control is squeezed into the first 60 degrees or so
> of rotation, while the rest of the rotation has little effect of
> audio. Linear tapers are just not built to manage audio. Log tapers,
> though, are perfect for audio applications. Its characteristics are
> suitable to the way our ears receive increasing or decreasing sounds.
> It gradually increases sound as the wiper is turned.
>
> Thus, audio tapers are potentiometers that are log tapers. This is the
> key separation from linear tapers.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer#Logarithmic_potentiometer) says this in addition to the above: -

> A logarithmic taper potentiometer is a potentiometer that has a bias
> built into the resistive element. Basically this means the center
> position of the potentiometer is not one half of the total value of
> the potentiometer. The resistive element is designed to follow a
> logarithmic taper, aka a mathematical exponent or "squared" profile. A
> logarithmic taper potentiometer is constructed with a resistive
> element that either "tapers" in from one end to the other, or is made
> from a material whose resistivity varies from one end to the other.
> This results in a device where output voltage is a logarithmic
> function of the slider position.

The 20K" part stands for 20 kohm i.e. the end to end resistance of the pot.

Answer (score 8):

"20K" is the resistance - 20 kilo-ohms.

["A" means logarithmic taper.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer#Resistance%E2%80%93position_relationship:_%22taper%22)

Probably.

Answer (score 7):

That would appear to be condensed specification of a 20 kilo-ohm potentiometer with a non-linear "audio taper".

Because hearing is roughly logarithmic, a useful volume control must be as well.